# How do I recognize squares, rectangles ... (like in TwoDots)?

Tags: grid, puzzle

I currently working on a small mobile game. Not a clone of TwoDots(!) but I need to recognize patterns like they do and I use the game as an example. How the game works? Players have to connect dots. Players can only connect a dot to its direct neighbor in the grid. So the next dot has to be left, right, above or below. Dots can only be added once to a sequence. Connecting a dot to one that is already part of the sequence closes the sequence.

See here http://youtu.be/8RDm6wQ9QbM?t=1m41s (just the next 20 seconds)

What I want to know is when a player connects dots, are there any enclosed dots?

[image: Patterns]

My idea was to store the players touch directions (next to the dots and their position in the grid). For the blue square this would mean {1,2,3,4} if you start from the bottom left and connect counterclockwise. Then I could simply check the number of directions in the array (=4). From my grid I know that the start-dot is [3|3] and the end-dot is also [3|3]. This means it has to be a square and there is nothing enclosed because it is the smallest possible rectangle/square.

The problem starts with bigger squares e.g. the purple one. Starting from the bottom left and connect counterclockwise again there would be the following sequence {1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4}. How do I know that this is a square/rectangle or some strange stuff and furthermore how do I know if there are any dots inside?

I can count all directions (3x1, 3x2, 3x3, 3x4) and see that all directions appear 3 times. It has 12 directions. 12 is divisible by 4 so it could be a square. But sadly 12 directions doesn't have to be a square nor a rectangle because [1,2,1,2,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4] would also close the pattern with the the same amount for each direction.

Well... the green one really makes my brain hurt. Green is definitely not a rectangle nor a square. I know that there might be any dots enclosed because there are more than 4 directions stored in the array and the start- and end-dot are the same but how do I get the three question marks? Same goes for the blue dots which are enclosed by the purple square.

I am totally lost here and I think... or better I hope I am overthinking/missing something here.

Thanks for your help!
proudcastle

```
Some Possible Squares:
4x OO |8x OOO |12x OOOO |16x OOOOO |20x... 24x... etc.
   OO |   O?O |    O??O |    O???O |
      |   OOO |    O??O |    O???O |
      |       |    OOOO |    O???O |
                        |    OOOOO |

Some Non-Square Rectangles:
6x OOO OO |8x OOO OOOO OO |10x OOOO OOOOO OO |12x OOOOO OOOOOO OO etc.
   OOO OO |   O?O OOOO OO |    O??O OOOOO OO |    O???O OOOOOO OO
       OO |   OOO      OO |    OOOO       OO |    OOOOO        OO
          |            OO |               OO |                 OO
                          |               OO |                 OO
                                             |                 OO

Some Strange Stuff
10x OOOOO   OOO  OOOO  OO   OOOO |12x  OOOOO  OOOO   ...
      O?O  OO?O  O?OO  OO   OOOO |     O??OO  O??OO  
      OOO  OOOO  OOO   OOO   OO  |     OOOO   OOOOO  
                       OOO       |
```

Comment: Okay. Solved it. I just draw a polygon and check if the dots are inside that polygon. I knew there has to be an easy way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way to detect any figures that have intersections or are "closed":

1. You know the list of dots that are used in the selection with their coordinates (from first selected dot to last) e.g.: (1,1) (2,1) (3,1), (3,2), (4,2) ...
2. If your list has two identical coordinates - you obviously have intersection
3. Profit!

This is usable for the kind of figures that are formed from two dots:

[image: two dots intersections]